# Persistent Shoping Cart not available on Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I use persistent shopping cart on Magento 1.7?

I can't find it under System->Configuration (Customers).

Current Configuration Scope is set to Default Config, but still can't see it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can guarantee that the persistent cart module is available in CE 1.7.
[Here is a link](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Persistent) to the module.
I think you are looking in the wrong place. The settings in the `System->Configuration` are should have a separate section.

[image: persistent]

If you don't see that section, check if the module is enabled. Look for the file `app/etc/modules/Mage_Persistent.xml` and check inside it of the tag `<active>` is set to `true`.

Comment: Editing Mage_Persistent.xml solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in my version 1.7.0.1 it is under "Customer" tab. Maybe your 'Current Configuration Scope' is not set to 'Default Config' and you cant see it.

Comment: Current Configuration Scope is set to Default Config, but still can't see it.